# Android ListView and ArrayAdapter/Arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I'm completely new to Java/Android and am stuck with listviews.

What I want is to have 4 lines in a row in listview with different font styles

```
rowlayout.xml

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/2"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/3"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/4"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I have this in a separate xml file

```
results.xml

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/TitleLbl" >
</Listview>
```

and my array adapter looks like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.2, Array);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

What I'm trying to do is get an arraylist (containing ID, name, surname and number) to populate the listview so that each information is on its own line in the row.

the array adapter above works, but each of the four informations is in their own row.

Can anyone help?

(also, I've scoured the internet to try and sort this out, but can't seem to find anything that helps me)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to use custom list view with custom array adapter. Refer this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx) for example.

Content:

The Android HelloListView ( http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html ) tutorial shows how to bind a ListView to an array of string objects, but you'll probably outgrow that pretty quickly. This post will show you how to bind the ListView to an ArrayList of custom objects, as well as create a multi-line ListView.

Let's say you have some sort of search functionality that returns a list of people, along with addresses and phone numbers. We're going to display that data in three formatted lines for each result, and make it clickable.

First, create your new Android project, and create two layout files. Main.xml will probably already be created by default, so paste this in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TextView
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Custom ListView Contents"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
  <ListView 
   android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Next, create a layout file called custom_row_view.xml. This layout will be the template for each individual row in the ListView. You can use pretty much any type of layout - Relative, Table, etc., but for this we'll just use Linear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
  android:textSize="14sp" 
  android:textStyle="bold" 
  android:textColor="#FFFF00" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView android:id="@+id/cityState" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView android:id="@+id/phone" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, add an object called SearchResults. Paste this code in:

```
public class SearchResults {
 private String name = "";
 private String cityState = "";
 private String phone = "";

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setCityState(String cityState) {
  this.cityState = cityState;
 }

 public String getCityState() {
  return cityState;
 }

 public void setPhone(String phone) {
  this.phone = phone;
 }

 public String getPhone() {
  return phone;
 }
}
```

This is the class that we'll be filling with our data, and loading into an ArrayList.

Next, you'll need a custom adapter. This one just extends the BaseAdapter, but you could extend the ArrayAdapter if you prefer.

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
  searchArrayList = results;
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return searchArrayList.size();
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return searchArrayList.get(position);
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
   holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityState);
   holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
  holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getCityState());
  holder.txtPhone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getPhone());

  return convertView;
 }

 static class ViewHolder {
  TextView txtName;
  TextView txtCityState;
  TextView txtPhone;
 }
}
```

(This is basically the same as the List14.java API demo)

Finally, we'll wire it all up in the main class file:

```
public class CustomListView extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
          Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
          SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults)o;
          Toast.makeText(ListViewBlogPost.this, "You have chosen: " + " " + fullObject.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }  
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(){
     ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

     SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
     sr1.setName("John Smith");
     sr1.setCityState("Dallas, TX");
     sr1.setPhone("214-555-1234");
     results.add(sr1);

     sr1 = new SearchResults();
     sr1.setName("Jane Doe");
     sr1.setCityState("Atlanta, GA");
     sr1.setPhone("469-555-2587");
     results.add(sr1);

     sr1 = new SearchResults();
     sr1.setName("Steve Young");
     sr1.setCityState("Miami, FL");
     sr1.setPhone("305-555-7895");
     results.add(sr1);

     sr1 = new SearchResults();
     sr1.setName("Fred Jones");
     sr1.setCityState("Las Vegas, NV");
     sr1.setPhone("612-555-8214");
     results.add(sr1);

     return results;
    }
}
```

Notice that we first get an ArrayList of SearchResults objects (normally this would be from an external data source...), pass it to the custom adapter, then set up a click listener. The listener gets the item that was clicked, converts it back to a SearchResults object, and does whatever it needs to do.

Comment: thanks @thinksteep, I had a look through it and adapted it to my code, but I'm still getting errors - 

`final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);`

that's being set to null and is throwing a NullPointerException

Comment: Have you extended listview? If so, getlistview should be enough. Update question with latest code.

Comment: I think I have - I've followed the example word for word, but replaced the bit where you populate the listview - what code should I add to the edit?

Comment: Java code and xml files also. Even same as example I wanted to see.

Comment: got the damn thing to work - the setContentView() after onCreate was set to main, rather than the xml file I wanted...

now to get the listview to display

Comment: found the error! If anyone else gets stuck with this (using the tutorial), don't forget to add `results.add(sr1);` beneath `sr1.setName();`